# Coloring game on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, chessboard

On an $8×8$ board, you and your friend play the following game. Initially, all the unit squares are white. First, you color any $n$ squares blue. Second, your friend chooses $4$ rows and $4$ columns, then colors all squares in those rows and columns black. What is the minimal $n$ such that, regardless of your friend's move, the board has always at least one blue square remaining?

Alright, I believe the minimal $n$ is $13$. I have proved that for $n = 12$, your friend always wins. There are always $4$ rows which have at least $8$ blue squares together. He can color those and $4$ columns for each remaining blue square (in the worst case). If you choose $8$ squares on the diagonal your friend can color first $4$ columns and last $4$ rows, if such diagonal goes from top left to bottom right.

I have tried to find a construction for $n = 13$ but, so far I have failed to do so.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Have you found some $n$ that work?  Some that don't?  Useful examples, I mean.  Clearly $n=64$ works for the former and $n=0$ works for the latter, but that doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: @lulu Sorry about that, I fixed it

Comment: What's the friend's strategy for $n=12$?  If I choose the $8$ diagonal elements, how does my friend block me?

Comment: there are always 4 rows which have at least 8 blue squares together, he can color those and 4 columns for each remaining blue square (in the worst case), if you choose 8 squares on the diagonal your friend can color first 4 columns and last 4 rows, if such diagonal goes from top left to bottom right.

Comment: Ah, right.  I'm drawing the wrong picture.  Good argument for $12$.

Comment: I hope people will vote to keep this open. OP has since provided their efforts in a comment, and I edited the post to include that context (and improve grammar).

Comment: Thanks for fixing my post! Also sorry for my bad grammar :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a possible case for $n=13$ that is impossible for your friend to remove?
[image: Potential solution]

Comment: Yep, this one works, thanks!